# Static inline functions in class

Tags: c++, inline, static-methods

I want to group my math functions. My math functions include many mathematical functions including the functions in "math.h" and some constant values. They are not in a class or namespace. Due to performance reasons, they are all inlined. But I want them grouped in a class if not possible namespace instead. I just want to use my functions like this:

```
MyMath::Pow(2, 2);
MayMath::PI;
```

So my question is; If I can use class, functions and values must be static I think but static methods can not be inlined since I know. I can use "MyMath" as a namespace if we can not find a solution.

Comment: Why would static methods not be able to be inlined, when defined inside the class definition?

Comment: I know static  modifier doesn't allow any other modifiers. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is your reasoning against using a namespace?

Comment: Do you realise that the `inline` keyword doesn't really have anything to do with allowing a function to be inlined? Many functions can be inlined if the compiler so chooses.

Comment: And what about constant data members. Must I make them constant not static and define get methods for them or what?

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü What data members would you make use of in a `Pow` function?

Comment: Not for pow function you are missing the whole idea. Math libraries contains lots of constant values like pi,euler constant, radian - degree conventions...etc. Also I create many for their divided values.

Comment: Thanks. I namespaced them all.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü Those are constants, which can (and should) be defined as `const`, and do not need to be member variables of a class.  Just declare them in the namespace.  You can take a look at the standard math library - it does all of this for you already and gives you a very good example of how to implement your own.

Comment: Yes. I namespaced them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You are attempting to put standalone functions (that do not belong in a class), inside a class - presumably because you are coming from another object-oriented language that does not let you write standalone functions.

To write a math library that includes functions like `pow`, `exp`, `log`, etc., create the namespace `MyMath` and define the functions.  There is no need for a class.

Comment: "presumably because you are coming from another object-oriented language that does not let you write standalone functions" Yes this is true.

Comment: Btw I dont think but is there any performance loss for namespace complexity. Between n1::foo() and n1::n2::n3::foo() ?

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü Just the amount of typing you have to do.

Comment: Now I am getting a symbol duplication error. There are some constant values in my FMath::FConvert namespace. I include my math header from "a.cpp" file. Then I include my "a" header from "b.h" but I am getting an error "b.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: RAD_TO_DEG_32 already defined in a.obj"

Answer (score 2):

static function/method may be inline too.

And methods defined inside the class are inline by default.

Answer (score 1):

> but static methods can not be inlined since I know

That's not true, static methods can also be inline.

Answer (score 1):

Static functions can be inline the same as all other functions. However, for your use case namespace is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`static inline` is perfectly valid.

If the storage class is extern, the identifier has external linkage and the inline definition also provides the external definition.

If the storage class is static, the identifier has internal linkage and the inline definition is invisible in other translation units.

In fact this is rare to use `inline` with storage class different from `static`.